# I want to launch a CMD (command prompt) and then pass two vaues and run the same using PERL

Tags: perl

As of now i am doing this:
launch a cmd then type in following command "D:\hi.pl" "D:\123\hi.xml" and hit enter.

I want to do the above procedure using a perl script as there are multiple xml files.

But not sure on how do i pass the path of the perl and XML file after cmd is launched.

Comment: Depending on a lot of things, it might be better to create a .bat script which runs each input file in turn. If `hi.pl` is competently written, it might be able to accept more than one input file on its command line, but that's a big if, and also depends on what it does. Anyway, the question as stated can't be answered without significant guesswork. Please edit your question to indicate what you have tried and how it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

According to [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html),

```
   $^X     The name used to execute the current copy of Perl, from C's
           "argv[0]" or (where supported) /proc/self/exe.
```

So, you could try:

```
system $^X, 'D:\hi.pl' 'D:\123\hi.xml';
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just type this at the command prompt:

```
for /r d:\123 %a in (*.xml) do @perl "D:\hi.pl" "%a"
```

this will launch `hi.pl` script for every `*.xml` file under `d:\123` and all subdirectories.